# 2 overloads have similar conversions - built-in operator integer[pointer-to-object]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have the following class:

```
class DictionaryRef {
public:
  operator bool() const;
  std::string const& operator[](std::string const& name) const;
  // ...
};
```

Then I try to use it:

```
DictionaryRef ref = ...;
ref["asdf"]; // error
```

The output complains about two overloads, but only lists one:

```
1>...: error C2666: 'DictionaryRef::operator []' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
1>    ...: could be 'const std::string &DictionaryRef::operator [](const std::string &) const'
1>    while trying to match the argument list '(DictionaryRef, const char *)'
```

However, mousing over the underlined portion, the popup window tells me that the second option is `built-in operator integer[pointer-to-object]`. Apparently it considers casting the object to bool, and then using the mysterious operator `int[char const*]`. I've never heard about this operator before, but apparently `3["asdf"]` is the same as `"asdf"[3]`? Does anybody *ever* use this syntax or is it some really old remnant from C? Besides, wouldn't it need two conversions to get there - first from `DictionaryRef` to `bool`, and them from `bool` to `int`?

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: I don't see a method that takes an `istring` in your `DictionaryRef` class; could you post all of the relevant code so that we can help you better?

Comment: @RedRoboHood: the [] operator actually takes istring (which is a typedef'd string_base with case insensitive traits), I just forgot to edit it out in the error message, but its the same thing if I use a regular string. The code is complete, I can paste it into a new project with and get the same error.

Comment: No, I don't have any other operators in that class. As I said, if I copy that class declaration (literally, with no extra members in place of //...) into a new project, I still get the same error.

Comment: There's no conversion from `bool` to `int` - `bool` is an integer type already.

Comment: Okay found another question that had a problem with the same operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850840/ambiguous-overload-for-operator-if-conversion-operator-to-int-exist. That's *really* obscure.. However, adding an explicit operator[] that takes char* fixes the issue.

Comment: Marking `operator bool()` as `explicit` should also solve your problem (in C++11).

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks that's actually a much better solution.

Answer (score 4):

It is counter intuitive but according to specification, subscripting is a commutative operator.

Paragraph 5.2.1 subscripting says :

*A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions
shall have the type “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration
or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.64 The
expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))*.

That means that when `x`is an array, and `i` an integral, `x[i]` **is** `*((x)+(i))` and is also `i[x]`.

That's the reason for the operator `int[char const *]` : it is the same operation as the operator `(char const *)[int]`.

For reference, C supports the same *feature* : in C language spec, 6.5.2.1 paragraph on array subscripting also says :

*One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other
expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.*

*A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).*